# How to tell if a given process opened files with O_DIRECT?

Tags: io, linux-kernel, posix

I would like to tell if a process has opened any files using O_DIRECT, but I can only examine it **after** the process was launched (i.e. strace is not an option).  I tried looking in /proc/$pid/fd/ to see if there was anything useful, but there wasn't.  My goal is to track down if any of several hundred users on a system have opened files with O_DIRECT.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since kernel 2.6.22, /proc/$pid/fdinfo/$fd contains a flags field, in octal.  See http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/proc.5.html

Comment: Thanks. This works. Unfortunately I'm stuck on 2.6.18 for the time being so I may try to backport this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's visible in `/proc` or elsewhere in user space.

With kernel code, it's possible:
1. Get the process's `task_struct` (use `find_task_by_pid`).
2. Go over files - use `task->files->count` and `task->files->fd_array`.
3. Look for `file->f_flags & O_DIRECT`.

Comment: Thanks. As pointed out in the other comment, there is a solution usable from userspace. It's only in newer kernels than what I have, so I may end up using this information or the newer kernel code to write a simple module to do this.